# Data of three month ago from today date from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing an PHP and mySQL based Blood Donating application. I want to show those blood donor who are didn't donate blood in last three month from today's date.How can I write the query for show those data..?

Comment: What is you table structure and what have you tried?

Comment: give the attributes of your table

Comment: [**SELECT something FROM tbl_name WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) <= date_col;**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: Just read documentation, it's easy: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: date column is varchar(100)

Comment: Change date column to DATE, not VARCHAR

Comment: select from table_name where date_sub(INTERVEL 90 Day)

Answer (score 0):

you can add query below

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND CURDATE()
```

OR you can use the below condition with your query.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `strtotime`

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d");
$date2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 month"));
```

Then put this dates into `BETWEEN` Sql statement like;

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '.$date1.' AND '.$date2.'
```